# Search button wont use onclick

Tags: javascript, html, hbs

I have this js file coded and when I try to call to my search button, nothing happens when I click the button! No error or anything just a clickable button. Any help?
index.hbs my search bar and button

```
input type="text" id="search-text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
  <button type="submit" id="search-button"><i class="fa fa-search" id="search-button"></i></button>
```

frontend.js

```
function executeSearch(){
    let searchTerm= document.getElementById('search-text').value;
    if(!searchTerm){
        location.replace('/');
        return;
    }
    let mainContent= document.getElementById('main-content');
    let searchUrl = `/posts/search?search=${searchTerm}`;
    fetch(searchUrl)
    .then((data) =>{
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) =>console.log(err));
}

const {execute} = require("../../config/database");

let searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
if(searchButton){
    searchButton.onclick = executeSearch;
}
```

Comment: check browser console for errors, `const {execute} = require("../../config/database");` looks like it doesn't belong in your clientside code, its probably error'ing and the code below it is not run

Answer (score 0):

im starting with this. Sorry if i could not help.
Instead of this:

```
if(searchButton){
    searchButton.onclick = executeSearch;
}
```

you could try:

```
searchButton.addEventListener('click',executeSearch());
```

Im editing this because looking to the previous comment i think im wrong understanding your problem but im leaving this here maybe help somebody.